# same output in values for different keys in for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and was trying to create a new dictionary from a dictionary with values in list format. Below please find my code:

```
dataset = {
    "a" : [3, 1, 7, 5, 9],
    "b" : [4, 8, 7, 5, 3],
    "c" : [3, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    "d" : [0, 5, 1, 5, 5],
    "e" : [3, 7, 5, 5, 1],
    "f" : [3, 6, 9, 2, 0],
}


for v in dataset.values():
    total = (sum(v))
    print(total)
for k in dataset:
    print(k)
dict1 = {k:total for k in dataset}
print(dict1)
```

My expected result is `{"a":25, "b":27, ..}`.

Instead, when i run the codes, the output is

`{'a': 20, 'b': 20, 'c': 20, 'd': 20, 'e': 20, 'f': 20}`

May I know which part of the codes I am wrong?

Comment: It only uses the last `total`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `total` is set to the last value in your `for v in dataset.values()` loop. You should try

```
dict1={k: sum(v) for k,v in dataset.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just storing the last `total` in your solution. Try doing this instead:

```
dataset = {
    "a" : [3, 1, 7, 5, 9],
    "b" : [4, 8, 7, 5, 3],
    "c" : [3, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    "d" : [0, 5, 1, 5, 5],
    "e" : [3, 7, 5, 5, 1],
    "f" : [3, 6, 9, 2, 0],
}

dict1 = {k: sum(v) for k, v in dataset.items()}
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

'total' changes after each iteration. Every time you go through a value in your dictionary and take the sum, you get a new total. So when the loop ends, total is the sum of the last list in your dictionary.

You are making each key in your dictionary have the value of the total for the last list. Instead, you should assign the total for each key inside the loop you are calculating total.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
dataset = {
    "a" : [3, 1, 7, 5, 9],
    "b" : [4, 8, 7, 5, 3],
    "c" : [3, 4, 1, 0, 0],
    "d" : [0, 5, 1, 5, 5],
    "e" : [3, 7, 5, 5, 1],
    "f" : [3, 6, 9, 2, 0],
}

result = {}
for (k, v) in dataset.items():
    result[k] = sum(v)

print (result)
```

output: 
{'a': 25, 'c': 8, 'b': 27, 'e': 21, 'd': 16, 'f': 20}

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `total` once for every list of values in `dataset`, but by the time you use dictionary comprehension to create your `dict1`, you're only using the last calculated value of `total`, which happens to be 20. (Dicts are not ordered, so `total` could have ended with any of your sum values, depending on which random order the values were visited in.)

Instead, you can do all of this in one line, using a handy function called `items()`, which turns a dict into a list of pairs (i.e.: 2-tuples) of corresponding keys and values. So you can rewrite your `dict1` code like this:

```
dict1 = {k: sum(v) for (k, v) in dataset.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the following part of your code, the total is updated for every value in the dataset dictionary, and then the total is updated to the sum of the last element of the dictionary, i.e. `[3, 6, 9, 2, 0]`, hence `total=20`

```
for v in dataset.values():
    total = (sum(v))
    print(total)
```

And then when you do `dict1 = {k:total for k in dataset}`, all values of dict1 are 20`.

Two ways to simplify this.

1. Iterate through the input dictionary and update the output dictionary at the same time, this is most efficient

```
total = []
dict1 = {}
for k, v in dataset.items():
    total = sum(v)
    dict1[k] = total
print(dict1)
#{'a': 25, 'b': 27, 'c': 8, 'd': 16, 'e': 21, 'f': 20}
```

2. Iterate through the values, and then make a list of all the sums, and then iterate through the keys, and make the output dictionary. Note that this is grossly inefficient, but can be treated as the intermediate step from going to the code you currently have, to the first approach.

```
total = []
dict1 = {}

#Create the list of sums
for v in dataset.values():
    total.append(sum(v))

idx = 0
#Use that list of sums to create the output dictionary
for k in dataset.keys():
    dict1[k] = total[idx]
    idx+=1
print(dict1)
#{'a': 25, 'b': 27, 'c': 8, 'd': 16, 'e': 21, 'f': 20}
```